# Where does HttpURLConnection store session id cookies on Android?

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpurlconnection

Where is it located and is it stored in plain text or encrypted? If it is not encrypted is there a way how to secure it from malware that can steal it from the phones storage?

Is it safe to store cookies like in a browser when I access my REST API backend through HttpURLConnection class?

Comment: Could you share an example snippet, just to possibly clear out any misunderstandings.

Comment: If you expect to get answers from the people who actually know about that stuff, make sure to always tag your questions correctly. Otherwise, nobody will see your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `HttpURLConnection` stores cookies in memory. When the VM exits (ie: the OS process hosting the application is killed), the cookie storage is gone.

On a rooted device it would be theoretically possible for a rogue application to spy on your application's memory, or just intercept the HTTP communication to view the cookies. On a non-rooted device this is not possible.

You can provide your own cookie manager instead of using the default implementation. You can then store the cookies wherever and however you want.

See
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#sessions-with-cookies

for more information.